# jQuery - .off() cannot remove the event listener

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function:

```
const foo = () => {
    // blablabla
};
```

I first add an event listener:

```
$('body').on('click', foo);
```

Then I try to remove it but fail:

```
$('body').off('click', foo);
```

It can only be removed with all other events:

```
$('body').off('click');
```

---

Update:

I try addEventListener & removeEventListener, still not working.

---

More explicit:

```
condition ? $('body').on('click', foo) : $('body').off('click', foo);
```

Does the if condition matter?

Comment: Can you describe the error you are getting for $('body').off('click', foo);?

Comment: @ankurnarkhede No errors just as I did not write the codes

Answer (score 1):

If you want to remove the event handler then [event.namespace](https://api.jquery.com/event.namespace/) should be used.

Additionally, attach an event handler to `document` instead of `body`

```js
const foo = () => {
  console.log('blablabla foo')
};
const foo2 = () => {
  console.log('blablabla foo2')
};


$(document).on('click', foo);
$(document).on('click.foo2', foo2);
$(document).off('click.foo2', foo2);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```